# Uploading an Image returns 400 error using an Django api

Tags: reactjs, django

I'm trying to upload an image from using fetch after I appended it to formdata

```
const fd = new FormData();
fd.append("image", this.state.offerimg);
console.log(fb)
const requestOptions = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
  },
  body: fd,
};
```

FormData console log

[image]

Django api: Im trying to store it in firebase storage and Im receiving a bad request, also I'm trying to print the file and its not printing.

```
class AddOfferView(APIView):

  parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser,)
  permission_classes = [AllowAny]
  def post(self, request):    
      image = request.FILES['image']
      print(image)
      image = storage.child("images/image.PNG" ).put(image)
    
        
      return Response({'userDoc': image}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK) 


System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
April 07, 2021 - 16:30:25
Django version 3.1.7, using settings 'loyalty_app_cms.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Bad Request: /api/add-offer
[07/Apr/2021 16:30:34] "POST /api/add-offer HTTP/1.1" 400 104
[07/Apr/2021 16:40:11] "GET /add-products HTTP/1.1" 200 3032
[07/Apr/2021 16:40:11] "GET /static/js/2.2a4e2c0c.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[07/Apr/2021 16:40:11] "GET /static/css/main.22590eba.chunk.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[07/Apr/2021 16:40:11] "GET /static/js/main.7dc050bc.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[07/Apr/2021 16:40:13] "GET /manifest.json HTTP/1.1" 200 3032
[07/Apr/2021 16:40:14] "GET /static/css/main.22590eba.chunk.css.map HTTP/1.1" 200 2437
[07/Apr/2021 16:40:14] "GET /static/js/main.7dc050bc.chunk.js.map HTTP/1.1" 200 57177
[07/Apr/2021 16:40:14] "GET /static/js/2.2a4e2c0c.chunk.js.map HTTP/1.1" 200 1544716
Bad Request: /api/add-offer
[07/Apr/2021 16:40:25] "POST /api/add-offer HTTP/1.1" 400 104
```

Comment: please update the answer with the server response, you can see it from in the browser console.

400 can be the csrf_token that you have to send with the post.

Comment: @DiegoPuente when I print request.body it works but when I print request.FILES it doesn't work

Comment: but I was talking about the browser console, 400 is an error and you will have more information with the server response.

Answer (score 0):

I was encountering the same issue. I fixed it by switching to a put request instead of a post.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).